# Is this graph of Wigner-Ville distribution OK?

Tags: fft, algorithms, time-frequency

I am studying some code for smoothed Wigner-Ville distribution.

update 3- solution, graph was over amplified in a 2d overdrive/oversaturation effect. if i divide by 20 only a line is visible.

Update - indeed there is a bug, the current image is from 128 samples of a $44.1\textrm{ kHz}$ signal where `sample[i] = sin[i/10.0]`; i.e. a $4410 \textrm{ Hz}$ sine wave, to fit inside the 128 samples.

As suggested by JazzManiac, [here is the code which is causing errors,](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/114667999/cohens1024ok.c) it's actually P Kootsookos Cohens.C code, with a minor change, instead of a .raw input audio TFD file i am using a sine wave array in `get_my_signal` function... A trivial and simple patch, wouldnt you agree? that can't be the error?!

I have a professional C programmer who has been coding for 30 years who provided this version of the code, it's just setting the `argc` and `argv` options in advance, to `spwvd`, `hamming`, and default window (was 128, is now 1024).

Is smoothed Wigner-Ville the same as smoothed pseudo Wigner-Ville?...

[image]

---

The original author (i.e. me) gets this for each of the three test cases:

[image]

Comment: Giving frequencies in Hz but not specifying the sampling rate is meaningless. And no, those do not look correct. You have weird artefacts at what appears to be the pixel level and the distributions do not look remotely correct. And unless you show your input signals and your code, you quite certainly won't get any deeper insight than this.

Comment: It looks like you provided us with a nice looking graphics, but without any axes. Please consider updating them.

Comment: Hi there, there is certainty that it's a bug, i thought it was aliasing due to the window size being only 128 samples... However JM is right there is indeed an error. I have edited the question and provided the code. Can you please confirm that the get_my_signal generated array should work isntead of a .raw file?

Comment: Thanks jojek regarding the graphics, it's actually a 2d graph supplied to the geometry shader of the graphics card, so all the dots are vertices.

Comment: Can't you use some better plotting tool, like `gnuplot` to generate a picture? I'd rather not have my software used to generate such poor images. :-)

Comment: Added [this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kootsoop/ccg/master/ccg/example_plot_three_wvds.png) that uses my code to create the three WVDs you're asking about. Seems to work for me.

Comment: Hi there, Thankyou Peter, if i can run your code to begin with, i can take the sounds of a sheep and a cricket and morph the harmonics from one to the other. I haven't been able to run your code because of the tfd input format requirement...

E:\dsp>ccg.exe -TS -wh -i128 -N128 -s1 e:\cohen1\sound.dat  ... i'm missing something! ... The graph i wrote is cool for placing 1gb of audio data into a graphics card and then i can zoom into the data interactively, i dont know gnuplot sorry. its a thorn in my side project :) im stuck.

Comment: I'll ask for advice on stackexchange because it's a complex topic of code versions. cohen's class generator is clearly awesome, however, the explanation text doesn't explain Q, X, arguments as argc's... or how to set the sample rate. At present if i run it is suggested with instructions, sample rate = 0, plot length = 0, because dev c++ simply compiles an incomplete algorythm. something is missing. i don't know what it is. what should i do? the code is awesome and incomplete / miscompiling and exceedingly complex.

Comment: Good to hear! I hope you can resolve it. I don't have access to Visual Studio right now, so am not much help.

Comment: I am getting well proportioned graphs now, sometimes the solution is so easy!!! i had to divide the output figures by 20 in order to not multiply all the transients into a mess. So now i am getting super clear straight lines, the last trouble is to figure out why a srate of 44100 is giving me the same as with 441hz and 120hz sine is dissapearing off the graph altogher... don't know why it could be de-tuned. Thanks i am onto something now. display in graphics card is awesome it enables fast zooming and brightness contrans adn post processing via ultra fast gpu parallel tricks very nice!

Answer (score 2):

> Is smoothed Wigner-Ville the same as smoothed pseudo Wigner-Ville?...

The Wigner-Ville is calculated using a window length that is the same as the signal length. The *pseudo* Wigner-Ville is computed using a window length that is shorter than the signal length.

So, no, they are not the same as they are smoothing two different things.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is over amplified. If the image in blue is divided by factor of 20, the transients vanish and only a line of the detected frequency is visible.